# Coming in contact with a virus from a Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop

I hve virus in my local system and I do office work using remote login. Let's say I do not open Bank or any other important sites on my local machine as I am afraid of viruses, if I open important sites like Bank or any other from my remote machine which I have logged into using remote desktop from the local machine than will my browsing be affected by the virus which I have on local machine?

Can this happen over Remote Desktop even? If so, how?

Answer (score 7):

If you have a virus on your system, **get rid of it and don't do anything sensitive before.**

If there is i.e. a keylogger included in the virus/malware, it still gets your keystrokes, because they originate from your local system.

Also, if there is file sharing enabled with the RDC session, there might be an attack vector opened this way.